# How remove contents of layout

Tags: python, kivy-language

My script allovs drawing lines by mouse. I want to delete last line by butoon Clear.(And sometimes delete gradually all lines) On stack overflow i found construction "self.ids.layout.remove_widget(self.ids.test)" How I create "self.ids.test" dynamically?. How must I modify this constuction for my script?  Thank You.

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), 1, 1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, mode='hsv')
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Clear', pos=(50,50))
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)

        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return parent

    def clear_canvas(self, obj):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an instruction such as Line is added to canvas this is returned, then a possible solution is to store those instructions in a list, and then remove it through the `remove()` method of canvas:

```
class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.lines = []

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), 1, 1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, mode='hsv')
            l = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))
            touch.ud['line'] = l
            self.lines.append(l)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Clear', pos=(50,50))
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return parent

    def clear_canvas(self, obj):
        if len(self.painter.lines) != 0:
            self.painter.canvas.remove(self.painter.lines[-1])
            self.painter.lines = self.painter.lines[:-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

if you want to clean all the instructions you must use `self.painter.canvas.clear()`

Comment: Thank You! Your answer was fast and intelligible. I searched process with using "id" (from definition graphic object) and i did not think abou using  definition object. Can I send qustion ocasionally directly to You?

Comment: @jasan Post them as now, and surely someone will answer them, maybe I'll be returned, but do not forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: @jasan check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , there they indicate